# Read lines from file, calling a consumer function for each line

Tags: java, performance, io, stream, callback

I wrote a function for iterating over a large file with performance in mind. It takes in an `InputStream` and reads until it reaches the end of the file. Whenever it detects an end of line it will call the `UnsafeConsumer#accept` with the line.

- `UnsafeConsumer` is the same as `Consumer<T>` but has a throws declaration on accept function
- `stream` has to be closed outside the function

I am am not sure if this is the fastest way to do this. Is there anything different that I could do?

```
public static void fileLines(InputStream stream, UnsafeConsumer<String,IOException> cons) throws IOException{
    StringBuilder lineBuild=new StringBuilder();
    int character;

    while(true){ //read file
        while(true){ //read line
            character=stream.read();

            if(character==-1){
                cons.accept(lineBuild.toString());
                lineBuild.setLength(0);
                return;
            }
            if(character=='\n'){
                cons.accept(lineBuild.toString());
                lineBuild.setLength(0);

                character=stream.read();

                if(character==-1) return;
                else if(character!='\r'&&character!='\n') lineBuild.append((char)character);
                break;
            }
            lineBuild.append((char)character);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you benchmark? What other variations did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You are conflating bytes with characters.  An `InputStream` produces bytes, but you implicitly interpret each byte as a character when you do `character=stream.read()` followed by the cast `lineBuild.append((char)character)`.  To be clear:

- `String`s consist of `char`s, not bytes.
- `InputStream`s and `OutputStream`s deal with bytes.
- `Reader`s and `Writer`s deal with characters.

To read lines as strings, first convert `stream` to a `Reader` using [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

Then, `BufferedReader` offers a [`.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) method.  Or, since you seem to be interested in a stream-based approach, call [`.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--), which produces a `Stream<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LineIterator` from [Apache commons IO library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.html).

For your case it may be like:

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file, "ISO-8859-1");
try {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        cons.accept(it.nextLine());
    }
} finally {
    it.close();
}
```

---

**UPDATE (follow up of comments)**

In case when you don't have `file` instance use [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html):

```
LineIterator it = IOUtils.lineIterator(stream, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: Where does `file` come from? And why did you choose UTF-8, breaking compatibility with the original code?

Comment: You are right, `file` is missed in the given question, but the author mentioned  about some large file. I assume a file instance is presented as well. "UTF-8" is just an example, there is a method without this parameter.